# Laravel dompdf custom font directory

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I installed laravel-dompdf (v0.8.5) in order to generate PDF files for users, and want to use some different font.

I manage to do it by declaring this font inside the blade file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ $title }}</title>

    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Jaldi';
            src: url({{storage_path('fonts/Jaldi/Jaldi-Regular.ttf')}}) format("truetype");
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Jaldi';
            src: url({{storage_path('fonts/Jaldi/Jaldi-Bold.ttf')}}) format("truetype");
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

When I generate the pdf (from browser), I get an additional entry in `storage/fonts/dompdf_font_family_cache.php`:

```
'jaldi' => array(
    'normal' => $fontDir . '/jaldi-normal_f26068eedd4182fc16a39c0f4c1a4678',
    'bold' => $fontDir . '/jaldi-bold_b51d304a463ce577b3942eb308c7c1ff',
),
```

My problem is that **new files are generated in the fonts directory**, which is part of my git repository. So when I do the same in other environment (dev or prod), **the git status is not clear anymore.**

I tried to change the target directory in `config/dompdf.php` config file:

```
  "font_cache" => storage_path('tmp/font-cache/'),

  "temp_dir" => storage_path('tmp/font-cache/'),
```

Still, the new files are generated in the fonts directory.

Any idea?

Comment: ./storage is in .gitignore and any changes in there should not be seen in version control.

Comment: That`s not write @kopz, in my case for some reasons the storage directory is not excluded from the repository, only parts of it.

Comment: Regarding your question... Make sure storage/tmp/font-cache exists and is writable

Comment: @kopz, thanks, but this is obvious. The problem is not that this directory is missing or missing the right permissions, but that the wrapper does not write the cached font files to this directory.

Comment: Test result: font_cache not writable or does not exist => writes cache to font_dir  (that's why I suggested you look at that).

Answer (score 1):

I spent two days on this problem..

**Right way:**

**1.** Create (or use) `public/fonts` folder. Put your `.ttf` fonts in it. That folder will be controled by git.

**2.** Create `storage/framework/cache/fonts` folder (storage/framework/cache already exists). Content **in** that folder will be gitignored (only just content, but not a `fonts` folder).

**3.** In `config/dompdf.php` set:

```
"font_dir" => storage_path('framework/cache/fonts'),
"font_cache" => storage_path('framework/cache/fonts'),
```

**4.** In your blade template put this styles:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FONTNAME';
    src: url('{{ public_path("fonts/FONTNAME-Regular.ttf") }}') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FONTNAME';
    src: url('{{ public_path("fonts/FONTNAME-Italic.ttf") }}') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FONTNAME';
    src: url('{{ public_path("fonts/FONTNAME-Bold.ttf") }}') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: bold;
}
body {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'FONTNAME';
}
```

---

**How do it do**

- Blade template will get font from `public/fonts` (as i think), and that folder still clear from any files wich created by dompdf;
- dompdf create the `dompdf_font_family_cache.php` and `.ufm` and `.ufm.php` files in folder wich is not in version control.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whether this is the normal behavior, but I found a solution that works for me.

I created two directories in `storage` directory  - `fonts` and `fontsCache`:

- `fonts` directory contains the `ttf` font files
- `fontsCache` directory is empty, writable (chmod 777) and excluded from my repository (.gitignore)

The `config/dompdf.php` file contains the following configuration:

```
"font_dir" => storage_path('fontsCache/'),
"font_cache" => storage_path('fontsCache/')
```

On the other hand, the `blade` file contains the following code:

```
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Jaldi';
            src: url({{storage_path('fonts/Jaldi/Jaldi-Regular.ttf')}}) format("truetype");
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Jaldi';
            src: url({{storage_path('fonts/Jaldi/Jaldi-Bold.ttf')}}) format("truetype");
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

In this way I keep a separation between the files which are controlled by my repository, and the files which are generated on-the-fly by dompdf.

Comment: "font_dir" => storage_path('fontsCache/'),
"font_cache" => storage_path('fontsCache/')

is this correct ?. just want to know for ensure

Comment: This is what I wrote in the solution I suggest, isn't it?

Comment: not working for me. i am using bangla font kalpurush. everything well but character dispatch. Lets example:Text should be আমি comes out like আ ম ি

Comment: No idea @raihan. Might be question of [text direction](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/)? Do you observe any difference with/without the font files and directories?